# Is "looking at it that way" correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

> Well, looking at it that way, it would be better to buy a house this year instead of next year.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looking at it that way, I don't think I have much to complain about.

[[American phrases.blogspot.co.uk/](http://american-phrases.blogspot.co.uk/2016/05/looking-at-it-that-way.html)

and

> Looking at it that way, I guess I can see what you mean.

[[Peter Salmon; The Emerald Tablet](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FhULZozdyZsC&pg=PT29&lpg=PT29&dq=%22looking+at+it+that+way%22&source=bl&ots=pa12ePg73o&sig=2qZtRtDVTlC8JPO0w5IBWGoyqsA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdzqqOk_nPAhUMIcAKHUXMDmUQ6AEINjAH#v=onepage&q=%22looking%20at%20it%20that%20way%22&f=false)]

are examples where the participle clause is obviously not misplaced, attaching to the next noun phrase 'I'.

However,

> Looking at it that way, it's always going to be critical.

[[Andy Roxburgh, theblizzard.co.uk](https://www.theblizzard.co.uk/articles/taking-the-initiative/)]

might be construed as a misplaced modifier, but can be interpreted as an emerging pragmatic marker (here, a referring-to-previous-context orientation marker) interchangeable with 'From that point of view'. '[When] Looked at that way ...' may be preferred by many.